# How can I avoid coloring tex followed by '$' in TexMaker, inside a minted?

Tags: math-mode, texmaker, minted, syntax-highlighting

I'm using `minted` for some parts of bash code inside my project. But when I write a `$` inside of it, TexMaker just colors everything else of green.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that? Thank you

Comment: You could put `#$` between the third and fourth lines.

Comment: I can't, because it would be shown in the PDF, and I don't need it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to "save" the content of the `minted` environment and `\end{minted}`, but you can at least add a `%$` on the line after `\begin{minted}` to fix the highlighting of whatever comes after.

[image: screenshot from texmaker]

On the other hand, the highlighting works properly in the `verbatim` and `lstlisting` environments, so it might be worth it to send a feature request to the maintainer, via
http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html#contact, asking for `minted` to be treated as a verbatim environment.